# Attached File Types

Tags: files

What is the best way to characterize the files that are attached? For example, i want when i upload a file on account record to declare that this is "Identity Copy". How could this be done ?

Comment: It is not really clear what exactly are you going to do that information in future. Custom fields on ContentDocument or naming convention could be an approach here

Comment: I try to create a custom field on ContentDocument but it does not let me to create it. I am not going to do something specific with this information, i just need to categorize it. For example, i want when uploading a file to select from a custom picklist field "File Type" a value and then upload the file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say ContentVersion, but it is impossible to set it as file is being uploaded using standard toolset. You could make a custom component where this is specified. There are some unimplemented ideas here -- https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cK4ZAAU

Comment: kurunve, thanks for your time, and your suggestion!